# What is the significance of $(n,m)=1$ in this proof that the Euler phi function is multiplicative?

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm, totient-function

In the proof reported in [Aaron Grecius's notes on Euler’s Phi Function (p. 1)](http://gauss.math.luc.edu/greicius/Math201/Fall2012/Lectures/euler-phi.article.pdf) where is the fact that $(n,m)=1$ actually used ? I'm having trouble understanding it's significance.

Comment: All the residue classes $\bmod 6$ are of the form $2a+3b$ with $a \in 1 \ldots 3, b \in 1 \ldots 2$. Not all the residue classes $\bmod 8$ are of the form $2a+4b$ with $a \in 1 \ldots 4, b \in 1 \ldots 2$. **To complete the proof**, when is $2a+3b$  coprime with $6$ ?

Comment: I don't like the proof presented there. I like to see this theorem as a corollary of the CRT.

Answer (score 0):

Its wrong otherwise, since e.g., $\phi(p^n) =(p-1)p^{n-1}$ and so $\phi(p^2) = (p-1)p$, but $\phi (p)\phi(p) =(p-1)^2$.